American English 'mouse': /maʊs/ or /mæʊs/?
In general American English, is the word 'mouse' pronounced /maʊs/ or /mæʊs/ with an 'æ'? I think it's the latter. Most online dictionaries, even Wiktionary give the former notation. Which is the correct one?

Dictionaries give a phonemic transcription, not a very precise one. /maʊs/ and /mæʊs/ aren't 2 different phonemes. You need to understand how dictionary pronunciation guides work.

The diphthong formed in English by ow (cow, fowl) or ou (doubt, mouse) is pronounced with either [aʊ̯] or [æʊ̯] in General American English (see, e.g., Wikipedia). [aʊ̯] is usually taught as the standard, hence the dictionary focusing on it. But I've heard both widely, and a chart of dialects suggests [æʊ̯] can appear in General American English, Miami, New York, and Philadelphia, and both Southern American English and AAVE use [æɔ̯], [æɒ̯] and similar (Wikipedia).

Slashes enclose phonemes. You're talking about phonetic qualities, or phones.

@Nardog Changed.

Which is part of why I very strongly prefer to write that one as /ɑw/, or if I can't figure out how to enter an ɑ character on some keyboard from one of Dante's Circles of Hell, then simply /aw/ even I have no [a]. In broad transcriptions one chooses the most convenient symbol, not the most phonetically accurate one possible as one might in a narrow transcription.
